# How do i get access to the elements inside of my mysql_fetch_row

Tags: php, mysql

I want to print a specific category count from my table how can i do that with using the correct references?

mysql:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['category'] . " " . $row['count'];

  echo "<br>";
  }
```

outputs:

```
auto/Bicycle 1
Clothing     7
electronics  4
```

now how can I print a specific category like clothing? (i would rather not just use $row[1])

Comment: Wouldn't you just insert a `where category='Clothing'` into your SQL and just print exactly as it was before?

Comment: I need all of them returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want reusable array you can just do it:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $result[$row['category']] = $row['count'];
}
```

And then just use `$result['Clothing']` for getting count of Clothing

Answer (score 0):

You loop through the array until you find the category you want:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($row["category"] == "Clothing"){
        echo $row['category'] . " " . $row['count'];
        break;
    }
}
```

if you know which category it is at the time of doing the SQL, you can order the query by its likeness to the category you are looking for - in which case the category you want will always be the first item returned by mysql_fetch_array - and will save you looping any further.

Also - as someone is bound to comment - you shouldnt use mysql_* any more, use mysqli_ instead.

Comment: @ZachNewsham Is there a better way to do this? The main goal will be to print the count of the categories onto a webpage in different spots and doing a loop foreach category count i need to display doesnt seem right

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is to select the number of products in each category. You didn't specify your schema but it would look something like this:

```
SELECT `category_name` , COUNT( `category_name` )
FROM `my_table`
GROUP BY `category_name`
```

You should be able to use this as a basis for your SQL statement, with some modifications. If not, post your schema here and I'll write the SQL statement for you.